# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied from python when using Sublime phpcs package, OSX 10.7

Tags: php, python, sublimetext, phpcodesniffer

Im trying to use Php Code Sniffer with Sublime, but in the sublime terminal I get the following every time I try to Sniff a file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 350, in run_
File "./phpcs.py", line 382, in run
File "./phpcs.py", line 270, in run
File "./phpcs.py", line 98, in get_errors
File "./phpcs.py", line 138, in execute
File "./phpcs.py", line 141, in parse_report
File "./phpcs.py", line 106, in shell_out
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Looks like there's a permissions issue somewhere, but:

- I have set phpcs file in /opt/local/lib/php/pear/bin as executable and checked all parent dir's
- I have set phpcs.py in sublime package dir as executable (though not sure if it needs it), ditto with parent dir's
- I have checked and I can run phpcs fine on command line. It is in PATH and it does what it is ment to do and returns results with no errors.

Update with output as per ms4py comment - a 'print cmd' at ln 105:

```
['php', '-l', '-d display_errors=On', u'/Users/pete/projects/portal/apps/frontend/modules/chilled/actions/actions.class.php']
[u'/opt/local/lib/php/pear/bin', '--report=checkstyle', '-n', u'--standard=PEAR', u'/Users/pete/projects/portal/apps/frontend/modules/chilled/actions/actions.class.php']
```

Comment: The permission error is due to phpcs.py is executing at line 105 (https://github.com/benmatselby/sublime-phpcs/blob/master/phpcs.py#L105). Place a `print cmd` before this line and tell us the command.

Comment: Check this out, here is the fix: https://github.com/benmatselby/sublime-phpcs/issues/4

Comment: Added that path in the config already when I had a different error, so I dont think it's that.

Comment: Well the setting should link directly to the executable:  `'/opt/local/lib/php/pear/bin/phpcs'`

Comment: Yeah. I take it back. I had put in the path minus the filename itself. Fixing the path has indeed fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the comments in this answer and marking as community wiki:

> Check this out, here is the fix:
>   [github.com/benmatselby/sublime-phpcs/issues/4](http://github.com/benmatselby/sublime-phpcs/issues/4) –  schlamar May 29 '12
>   at 13:47
>
> Well the setting should link directly to the executable:
>    `'/opt/local/lib/php/pear/bin/phpcs'` - schlamar May 29 '12 at 14:15

As explained in the github issue there is a new setting in phpcs to fix this issue by allowing the user to provide a path to the php cs executable should Sublime fail to find it automatically:

`phpcs_executable_path`